# edit and save the already existing data from database in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

models.py is

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publisher_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    author=models.ForeignKey(Author)

    def __unicode__(self):
        ..........

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    age=models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        ........

    def books(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(author=self)
```

I need to perform edit and save the already existing data in a table from database.I am using 2 models.since i did for doing the same by single table,have some confusion to perform with two table.I am a learner of django.plz help me with this

plz check my views.py for edit option.

```
def editbook(request,book_id):
    if request.POST:
        book_name =request.POST['book_name']
        publisher_name =request.POST['publisher_name']
    books=Book.objects.filter(book_id=book_id).update(book_name=book_name, publisher_name=publisher_name)

    first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        age = request.POST.get('age')
    author = Author.objects.update(first_name = first_name,last_name = last_name,email=email,age=age)
        return redirect('/index/')
    else:
        books = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
    return render_to_response('editbook.html',{'books':books},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

ya.this is not working properlly.plz guide me how to perform that.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def editbook(request,book_id):
   books = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id) 
   if request.POST:
        book_name = request.POST.get('book_name')
        publisher_name = request.POST.get('publisher_name')

        books.book_name = book_name
        books.publisher = publisher_name
        get_author = books.save()

        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        age = int(request.POST.get('age'))

        author = Author.objects.get(pk=get_author.author_id)
        author.first_name = first_name
        author.last_name = last_name
        author.email = email
        author.age = age
        author.save()

        return redirect('/index/')

    return render_to_response('editbook.html',{
        'books':books
    },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: why u declared author_id as Pk,it was Foreign key know in model.how is it ok

Comment: The foreign key you mention is in the book model. That author_id is the primary key of the author which also connect to the book author

Comment: ya,but i am not using form in my app.i have to collect the values and directly render to sditbook.html.The code u given also not functioning properlly

Comment: i am getting this error"unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Comment: I'am not using form as what you have said before. WHat I post is hardcoded which you like

Comment: About the error in indentation your facing now is not my fault. Maybe you copy and paste my code without notice the proper indentation. You must use spaces not tab for indentation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25495/discussion-between-user2086641-and-catherine)